# Compute partition function

Tags: markov-process, conditional-random-field

I'm given a distribution on 3 discrete variables $x, y, z$ which is defined as

$$p(x, y, z) = \frac{1}{Z} \psi(x, y, z) = \frac{1}{Z} \phi_1(x, y) \phi_2(y, z)$$

where $x, y$ can take up value among $\{0, 1\}$ and $z$ can take up value among $\{0, 1, 2\}$.

I'm also given all possible (discrete) values for $\phi_1(x, y)$ and $\phi_2(y, z)$.

That is, $\phi_1(x=0,y=0)=1; \phi_1(x=0,y=1)=2; \phi_1(x=1, y=0)=3;\phi_1(x=1, y=1)=4$

And the same list for $\phi_2(y, z)$

I'm asked to compute $\psi(x,y=1,z)$

Is it just the product of $\phi_1(x, y=1) = 4+2=8$ and $\phi_2(y=1,c)$ (sum of all $\phi_2$ where $y=1$)?

Did I miss anything here?